# UserManager.FindByEmail() returning Null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement email address based usernames in AspNet.Identity for MVC5. My application works find as long as there is a registered email/username on the system.

I just discovered that if the user does not exist and tries to login an exception gets thrown on Line 72.

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>      Line 71:    //Add this to check if the email was confirmed.
>      Line 72:    var userid = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email).Id;

Here is my code.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Add this to check if the email was confirmed. 
        var userid = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email).Id; 
        // **Line 72. 'userid' is empty.**

        // Here is my attempt but doesn't do anything. 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userid)) {
            ModelState.AddModelError("","You are not registered!");
        }

        if (!UserManager.IsEmailConfirmed(userid))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "E-mail address has not been confirmed.");
            return View(model);
        } 
    }  
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);  
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The same problem. Actually all Find* methods return null for some reason. Target users were seeded while creating the app.

Comment: Resolved. Just had wrong Auth middleware configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I added the code below and it works but I still don't understand how FindByNameAsyn() method actually work as opposed to FindByName()? Also
 Is there a better way to do this? Thank you!

```
// Code that works. 

var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);

if (user == null)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code below and worked for me:

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        string userName = "";   // to be used as arg to PasswordSignInAsync

        // you'd better declare the appropriate Type.
        // using "var" doesn't work here - I don't know why...
        ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.UserName);

        if (user != null)
        {
            // found an existing user having the given Email
            // so let's get it's UserName to test SignIn
            userName = user.UserName;
            // just for debugging - check your AspNetUser table 
            // ModelState.AddModelError("", userName + " ID = " + user.Id.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            // Hum... no email found - perhaps the user is really trying the UserName
            // Perhaps Email != UserName  
            // It's interesting to give the user the option to use Email or UserName
            // to get authenticated.
            // Let's play, then! 
            userName = model.UserName;
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, model.Password, 
                                model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);

        // from here on, it's the scaffolded code...

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Hope it's useful, even after all that time.

Please, let us know if your problem was solved.
Regards.